# calculate Transfer entropy in r

Tags: r, transfer, entropy

```
library(TransferEntropy)

x = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

y = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

computeTE(x,y,3,1,"MI_diff",safetyCheck = T)
```

> Error in computeTE(x, y, 3, 1, "MI_diff", safetyCheck = T) : 
>     Points with same coordinates in the X tree (add noise).

I have binary data like x and y and i need to calculate transfer entropy between them, I used R and performed above steps but i am getting error !!But when i use :

```
computeTE(x,y,3,1,"Correlation")
```

this works but i want to know why
and my actual data have 43200 records when i give that to same code R crashes

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the format of data if the data is in doubble format then r wont accept it thus it is crashing